# Any way to get the amount of rows returned using mysqli prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Wondering if there is a way to get the amount of rows returned from a query using mysqli prepared statements, sort of like

`mysql_num_rows($query);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you're doing something like:

```
$result = $statement->execute();
```

You can get the number of rows with

```
$result->num_rows;
```

[See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: hhahah easy enough, missed that one. thanks alot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$num_rows = $result->num_rows($result);
```

Comment: hhahah easy enough, missed that one. thanks alot for the help.