# Check if mysqli fetch is empty

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there any efficient way to check if the fetch loop of mysqli will not run (because the query returns an empty table)?

```
while ($sql->fetch()) {
  // ... something
}

if (sql fetch returned empty array) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // ...
}
```

Should I implement this by myself or does mysqli have any pre-made statement to do this?

Comment: Check the `num_rows` property first, of course. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: thanks! that's what I was searching for... You should post it as the answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to get the amount of rows returned using mysqli prepared statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607487/any-way-to-get-the-amount-of-rows-returned-using-mysqli-prepared-statements)